# Does Redgate change automation tool builds repositories containing procedures with JSON functions in them?

Tags: jenkins, build, ssms, redgate

We want to use Redgate continuous automation tool to continuously deploy changes done to the database.

The build is generated without any issues if we are not using JSON functions in the procedure.

Sample code in the procedure -

```sql
begin
select(select * from x for json path) as data
end;
go
```

When "for json path" is not used the build is generated successfully.

Should some plugin be installed so that Redgate tool processes json functions?

What is the fix to be applied?

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to Redgate's support team? My experience with them has generally been positive.

Comment: Hey, quick question. Exactly which Redgate tool are you using? There are a couple. I can get you better help if I know where to focus.

Comment: @Larnu - Thank you for the response! I reached out to Redgate's support team and am waiting for a reply.

Comment: @GrantFritchey - We are using Redgate SQL change automation tool. We have installed the Redgate sql change automation plugin in Jenkins. The issue arises when build step is performed.

Comment: I sent this question to our team. Hopefully you'll get an answer soon, but might not. Lots of people on holiday at the moment.

Comment: The issue is resolved. We passed LocalDB as test database where initial testing is done. LocalDB does not support some JSON functions. So it was replaced with an SQL Server database. The build got generated successfully. Thanks for the help!